# Need help getting my ForEach Query to Work

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am hoping someone can help me with this code as it has taken me weeks and I am now close to hanging myself.

Firstly I have two tables:
Table 1, DynamicDocType 
    DocTypePK,(AI primary key)
    DocType (Document Name - Varchar)

And Table 2, 
    DocTypePk,  (AI pk)
    CompanyFk, (foreign key, see next paragraph)
    DocType, Document Name - Varchar)

I am trying to use a php event when adding a new client, that looks up the master table (Table 1), and populates the child table with a full set of records.  At the moment the Master Table contains 7 records, Manual, Policy, Procedure, Process, Work Instruction, Guidance and Form.

The code I am trying to use is as follows:

```
$rs10 = CustomQuery("SELECT DocType as DocType FROM DynamicDocType");
$data10 = db_fetch_array($rs10);
foreach($data10 as $row1)
    {
        CustomQuery("INSERT INTO CompanyDocType (CompanyFk, DocType) values  ('".$values["CompanyPk"]."', '$row1[DocType]')");
    }
```

However this isnt working, when I do a print_r, all it does is either the first letter from each row, or just the first letter of the first row, ie "M" and stops there.

This is confusing me as before I used to run a code similar to this, on exactly same platform, software etc:

```
$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM global_doctypes";
$rs5 = CustomQuery($sql5); 
$results5 = $rs5;
while ($row = $results5->fetch_assoc())
{
$sql6 = "INSERT INTO documents_doctypes (companyfk, doctype, doctypeID, doctypeabv) values
 ('".$values["companypk"]."', '$row[doctype]', '$row[doctypepk]', '$row[doctypeabv]')";CustomQuery($sql6);
}
```

Which now gives me a fatal error saying Undefined method (for fetch_assoc), however I have checked and I know mysqlnd is installed on server.

It seems that the foreach statement is the best one to go with, but I cant get it to loop properly, can someone please please help

Comment: Can you share print_r part?

Comment: Not much to see, it just says "M" which is the first letter of first row, i.e., "Manual", but here prntscr.com/71wib5

Comment: forgot to say that is using print_r($row1["DocType"] within the foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things that could be wrong with your code.  Probably, it has to do with what ever the "CustomQuery" function returns.  We are not able to reach into your computer and discern what that function is or does but it has to be bad, because you don't even have any parameters other than a string of sql, which means that any db connectivity must be driven by Globals.  Ugh.

You are also apparently using things based on the deprecated mysql_ api.

However, the main thing it appears you could use help with is that you don't seem to understand good clear ways of interpolating php strings.  I hope this will help you clean up your code a bit.

Here's what you have:

```
$sql6 = "INSERT INTO documents_doctypes (companyfk, doctype, doctypeID, doctypeabv) values ('".$values["companypk"]."', '$row[doctype]', '$row[doctypepk]', '$row[doctypeabv]')";
CustomQuery($sql6);
```

In this case you are using the php interpolation method of defining a string:

```
$sql = "....";
```

With interpolation, your variables embedded in the string will be resolved at runtime.

```
$foo = 'Loki';
$greeting = "Hello $foo!";
echo $greeting;
// You get Hello Loki!
```

A string constant is created using single quotes.

```
$foo = 'Loki';
$greeting = 'Hello $foo!';
echo $greeting;
// You get Hello $foo!
```

In your case, apparently you have found out that an array element with a key doesn't interpolate into your string, so you're starting interpolation, and then mixing in the array elements you fetched by doing all that messy concatenation.  You seem confused because you have double quotes and single quotes, and in some cases you omitted the single quotes for the array keys.  This is complicated with SQL because single quotes are used in the value statement to denote a string constant, which you are using.

The secret is, to just put a block {} around the array elements and you'll be able to interpolate the values simply and clearly in your code.

```
   $sql6 = "INSERT INTO documents_doctypes (companyfk, doctype, doctypeID, doctypeabv) values ('{$values['companypk']}', '{$row['doctype']}', '{$row['doctypepk']}', '{$row[doctypeabv]}')";
CustomQuery($sql6);
```

I also have to question the data type of companyfk.  If that is an integer value then you should not be putting single quotes around it, as it is not a string, but rather a numeric type.

```
$sql6 = "INSERT INTO documents_doctypes (companyfk, doctype,   doctypeID, doctypeabv) values ({$values['companypk']}, {$row['doctype']}', '{$row['doctypepk']}', '{$row[doctypeabv]}')";
CustomQuery($sql6);
```

Comment: Ok all very good points and I will make a note of sitting down and brushing up on the points you make, however can you take my first loop code and show me how you would do it, just a quick example?

Comment: By the way the second code you have zoned in on, isnt the one I was using, I put that on there as an example of what I did prior to this, but now am looking for a foreach statement

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone runs across this again, I managed to get my function to work by using the following code:

```
global $dal;
$tblDynamicDocType = $dal->Table("DynamicDocType");
$rs10 = $tblDynamicDocType->QueryAll();
while ($data10 = db_fetch_array($rs10))

{
    CustomQuery("INSERT INTO CompanyDocType (CompanyFk, DocType) values  ('".$values["CompanyPk"]."', '$data10[DocType]')");
}
```